# Regular surface given by the implicit function theorem: curvature

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S=\{(x,y,z): \, F(x,y,z)=0\}$ be a regular surface. How can I express a base for the tangent plane in a given point $P=(x_p,y_p,z_p)$ and the gaussian curvature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit normal vector to the surface is given by $n =\frac{\nabla F}{||\nabla F||}$, so a basis for the tangent space can be obtained by choosing one for the orthogonal complement of $\nabla F$

A formula for the curvature for most representations of surface can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature)

**Edit:** A proof of this and many other useful formulas for surfaces in Euclidean $3$-space can be found in Michael Spivak's Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry, Vol. 3. There you will find Chapter 3: A compendium of Surfaces. In the second edition the case you are interested in is discussed on page 202 ff.

Comment: Where can I find a proof for this formula?

Comment: @TheWanderer I added a reference to the answer.